# Are raffles halaal or haraam? (Shia view please)

Tags: quran, halal-haram, shiism, gambling

Recently I saw a Shia mosque holding a fund raising raffle ticket competition where the winner would get a fully paid for umrah trip.

**What is a raffle?**

> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffle) - A raffle is a gambling competition in which people obtain numbered
>   tickets, each ticket having the chance of winning a prize. At a set
>   time, the winners are drawn from a container holding a copy of every
>   number. The drawn tickets are checked against a collection of prizes
>   with numbers attached to them, and the holder of the ticket wins the
>   prize.

**Is gambling haraam?**

> [Sahih international translation of the Quran 5:91](http://quran.com/5/91) - Satan only wants to cause between you animosity and hatred through
>   intoxicants and gambling and to avert you from the remembrance of
>   Allah and from prayer. So will you not desist?

**The question:**

Are raffles haraam, even if they are used for fund raising purposes where the winner gets a trip go do an umrah?

Shia view please.

Comment: "What is the Shia definition of gambling" is probably what I should have asked?

Answer (score 2):

no matter what the purpose is, if you're giving money for the CHANCE to win, and the win is not definite, then it is haraam, whether it's to help the poor, cure a sickness or even to stop war, no competing with your money!

Comment: Please provide islamic reference. Jazaklahir

Answer (score 1):

gambling is totally haram.
some years ago (about 5-6), in I.R.Iran some NGO's made some raffles for orphans and poor people but almost all of shiah's marjas(it the same as 'marja taghlid' or greatest religious men) banned it and declared it as HARAM.
but certainly not all people do as they told.